# read vtd-xml (ximpleware) xml in java

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

I try to read a XML File with Ximpleware. My Problem is, that I don't find usefull examples or tutorials.

I want to read following XML:

```
   <title name="bliblablu">
        <program>
            <text lang="1">
                <![CDATA[English]]>
            </text>
            <text lang="2">
                <![CDATA[Francais]]>
            </text>
            <text lang="3">
                <![CDATA[Deutsch]]>
            </text>
       </program>
       <program>
            <text lang="1">
                <![CDATA[Afrikans]]>
            </text>
            <text lang="2">
                <![CDATA[Portuges]]>
            </text>
            <text lang="3">
                <![CDATA[Italiano]]>
            </text>
       </program>
   </title>
```

And what I want is a simple print out like below.

1: English
2: Francais
3: Deutsch
1: Afrikans
2: Portuges
3: Italiano

How can I do this?
I read the following [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641784/how-to-get-attribute-values-from-select-path-or-select-attribute-ximpleware), [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262030/parse-xml-file-using-vtd-xml).
And I tried with the following Code, but it does not work.

```
import com.ximpleware.AutoPilot;
import com.ximpleware.NavException;
import com.ximpleware.VTDGen;
import com.ximpleware.VTDNav;
import com.ximpleware.XPathEvalException;
import com.ximpleware.XPathParseException;
...


final VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.parseFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), false);
VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
final AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
ap.selectXPath("/title/program/text");

Log.d(ap.evalXPathToString());

int i = 0, j = 0;
String languageNr = "", languageText ="";

while ((i = ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
    j = vn.getAttrVal("lang");

    // z = vn.toNormalizedString(i);
    if (j != -1) {
        languageNr = vn.toString(j);
        AutoPilot ap2 = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap2.resetXPath();
        ap2.selectXPath("/ticker/program/text");
        ap2.selectElement(Integer.toString(j));
        languageText = ap2.evalXPathToString();

    }
    Log.d(languageNr);
    Log.d(languageText);
}
```

My output is:

1: English
2: English
3: English
1: English
2: English
3: English

Thanks for every kind of help
Lukas

Comment: How to read xml file in java is explained here https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I assume you know xpath reasonably well... so I don't see why you need another AutoPilot... Here is the first version.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class simpleRead {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws VTDException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\title.xml", false)){
            return;
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/title/program/text/text()");
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            System.out.print(" "+vn.toString(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second version that does the same thing...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class simpleRead {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws VTDException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\title.xml", false)){
            return;
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/title/program/text");
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            int k=vn.getText();
            if (k!=-1)
            System.out.print(" "+vn.toString(k));
        }
    }
}
```